# DPM (Data Protection Manager) Does Not Restore Column of Type 'User'

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, backup

I have DPM set to back up my SharePoint farm down to item level.

When I try to restore an entire list (custom list) to a new SharePoint site that I've created for it, the list restores successfully with no errors in DPM; BUT I have a column in the list of type `User` that does not restore and contains nothing.

Any ideas why this column is blank?

**Update**

Rather than restore the entire list to a new location, I have just tried to restore a single item in the original list after first deleting it, and the same issue occurs. The `Created By` and `Modified By` fields of the item are set to `System Account`, however.

Interestingly, if I restore a file in a *document library*, the `Created By` and `Modified By` are correctly set to the appropriate user.

Answer (score 0):

This has been an issue for as long as I can remember, holds true with saving lists as templates with people or lookup values. I suspect under the hood, the value is still being saved as ID#;Display Name of the user. When restored into another environment, it cannot verify that user and drops it.

You could try copying the User Information List over first, then try restoring the list and see if that has any effect.

Comment: Eric, I had the exact same suspicion initially. But - I'm restoring the list to a subsite of the original list (just as a test) - so to the same site collection at least. So I would have thought SharePoint should have been able to resolve the user.

Comment: Is it possible to restore the list without conent and then migrate data in a separate process?

Comment: The restore options in DPM seem to be quite limited. I can either restore the list to the original location, in which case I presume the list will be over-written, or I can restore to a new location, which is what I'm trying here. There are no other restore options for a list. So not sure how I would restore the list without content and then restore only content?

Comment: The `Created By` and `Modified By` fields are set to `System Account`. See my update to the question on my attempt to restore a file in a document library, rather than a list item in a list.